# Snap in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, snap

Completely confused with this new feature **snap**. I know this might be detailed question-answer but I need to know some info regarding it.

I have read that new application format, snap which can be installed by default in the latest long-term support release alongside traditional deb packages. So, Does it mean are there packages with `.snap` extension like `.deb`? Then, How to install?

The user can use newer versions of apps on older versions of Ubuntu without forsaking the stability of your entire system.  Is this the only difference between deb and snap? Does it only exist to LTS version or for non-LTS too?

With this, it is also said that *Creating snaps is simplified for developers with the introduction of a new tool called “snapcraft” to easily build and package applications from source and existing deb packages.* Is it useful to desktop user or only for developers ?

Comment: +1.  There has been much publicity about the Snap package format and how it changes things for developers - but information what changes it will impose on the end user is hard to find.

Answer (score 19):

snap packages are installed through the snap command. More information is [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/252047/how-to-install-and-manage-snap-packages-on-ubuntu-16.04-lts/) and [here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/).

> ### Search for available snap packages
>
> To see a list of all available packages in the store, open a terminal
>   and run the following command:
>
> ```
> snap find
> ```
>
> To search for a specific package by name, just add your search term to
>   the end of the snap find command:
>
> ```
> snap find name
> ```
>
> For a more complete search–searching package descriptions as well as
>   package names–just pipe the output of the snap find command through
>   the grep filtering tool, like so:
>
> ```
> snap find | grep search
> ```
>
> ### How to install a snap package
>
> To install a snap package, use the following command, specifying the
>   package by name. Because this makes changes to the system, you have to
>   add `sudo` before the command to run it with root privileges.
>
> ```
> sudo snap install package-name
> ```
>
> The snap command will download and install the snap package you
>   specified, displaying the progress in the terminal window.
>
> You can launch the application you installed like any other
>   application. If it's a graphical application, it should appear in your
>   desktop's applications menu. Otherwise, just start typing the
>   application's name at the terminal and press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to
>   automatically complete it. You can then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to
>   launch the application or run the command you installed.
>
> ### How to update a snap package
>
> To update an installed snap package, run the following command,
>   specifying the package's name. If a new version of the snap is
>   available, it will be downloaded and installed.
>
> ```
> sudo snap refresh package-name
> ```
>
> There doesn't appear to be a command that updates all installed snap
>   packages at the moment, but we wouldn't be surprised to see one added
>   in the future.
>
> ### How to list your installed snap packages
>
> To list your installed snap packages, run the following command
>
> ```
> snap list
> ```
>
> You can use this command to search your installed packages, too –j ust
>   pipe the output through grep again:
>
> ```
> snap list | grep search
> ```
>
> ### How to remove a snap package
>
> To remove an installed snap package from your computer, run the
>   following command:
>
> ```
>  sudo snap remove package-name
> ```
>
> ### View recent changes
>
> Run the following command to view a list of system changes. This
>   displays a list of the snap packages you've recently installed,
>   refreshed (updated), and removed, along with the times those
>   operations took place.
>
> ```
> snap changes
> ```
>
> ### See more operations
>
> To see more snap command operations, view the snap command's manual
>   with the following command. Use the arrow and page up/down keys to
>   scroll through the manual. press the <kbd>q</kbd> key to quit when
>   you're done.
>
> ```
> man snap
> ```

---

In effect, a .deb package includes an executable plus the information needed to install it into the system: where it goes, what it depends upon, etc. Compare this with a snap package, which includes the executable *and any necessary dependencies* - think of it like static linking of libraries versus dynamically calling in what's installed elsewhere on the system.

The idea is that you could have a stable version A library on the OS, but a new application might demand version B. With a .deb, you'd need to upgrade A, and that might in turn impact some other packages; with snap, the application would come bundled with version B for its sole use, so the system-wide version A remains untouched.