# How do I uninstall discord on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I recently ran into a problem with discord updating and I want to uninstall it via command line to reinstall it, but I dont know how. would anyone know how to do that?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uninstall a .deb package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22200/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-package) and [Snap in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763078/)

Answer (score 10):

The .deb install on discord's website installs a package named "discord"
try running

`sudo apt-get remove discord`

in your terminal. Then reinstall it the same way you installed it in the first place. I don't know if this will work if you installed it a diffirent way.

Edit: I also previously got the discord message to update this afternoon,  and ran the command and used this file to update discord: [Discord .deb install from discordapp.com](https://discordapp.com/api/download?platform=linux&format=deb)

Answer (score 9):

In ubuntu 18.04 discord can be easily installed, removed with snap:

```
sudo snap remove discord

sudo snap install discord
```